# Maven Project + Apache Maven + Apache archiva

Tags: maven, pom.xml, archiva

This is what I did

1. As a first step, I have configured the Apache Archiva and the service runs perfectly as a standalone service though it created some trouble for me while trying to run in tomcat.
2. Edited the setting.xml in the MAVEN_HOME pointing to the Apache Archiva repository by adding mirror.

With the project's pom.xml, I see the following

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Central Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Should I remove this to make my Archiva repository effective? I am afraid that this code makes a direct call from the Central repository without making use of the Archiva. Is this correct? Please advise

Comment: Why not simply have a try by yourself?  Purge something from your local repo which force the project to get it from remote repo, and then you can inspect which repository it is connecting to

Comment: Thanks. It only tries in the archiva repository. The pom.xml repository listing does not seem to have an effect on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. This repository is the default one (and no need to declare it in your pom).
Just a mirror with `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>` in your settings

Comment: I did not change anything. In fact, eclipse doesn't allow me to delete this area. Only editable portion is the dependency part. Thanks a lot